# Steps of Verify Completeness of a Normed Vector Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question

The textbook by Kreyszig on functional analysis identifies three steps to verify the completeness of a space:

1. Construct an element to use as a limit: $x$
2. Prove that $x$ is in the space considered
3. Prove that $x_n \rightarrow x$ (in the sense of metric)

I'm confused by these steps. In particular, if we stop at step 2, aren't we done? If $x$ is a limit point in a metric space (in fact a normed space here), aren't we gauranteed that a sequence hits it? (Take balls of radius $1/n$)

Answer (score 1):

Completeness means every Cauchy sequence converges. More precisely, every sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $\|x_n-x_m\| \rightarrow 0$ as $n,m\rightarrow \infty$, converges$^3$, to some point$^1$, in the space$^2$.  You need point 3 because of the definition of convergence in metric spaces.

What if you took the sequence $1/n$ in $[0,1]$? I could construct the candidate limit "1". I could show that 1 belongs to the space. But I couldn't show convergence of the sequence to 1.

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding correctly: so are there metric spaces with limit points   that are not the limit of some Cauchy sequence?

Comment: There are examples of 1,2, but not 3 (which I gave). There are examples of 1,3, but not 2 (take (0,1] and 1/n). And (vacuously) no examples of 2, 3, but not 1.

Comment: To answer your question, no-- because any limit point is the limit of a cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's  the  full context (excerpted from the text):

> In various applications a set $X$ is given (for instance, a set of sequences or a set of functions), and $X$ is made into a metric space. This we do by choosing a metric $d$ on $X$. The remaining task is then to find out whether $(X, d)$ has the desirable property of being complete. To prove completeness, we take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ and show that it converges in $X$. For different spaces, such proofs may vary
>   in complexity, but they have approximately the same general pattern:

  (i) Construct an element
  $x$
  (to be used as a limit).
  (ii) Prove that $x$ is in the space considered.

  (iii) Prove convergence $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ (in the sense of the metric).

**Note:**$\;$The point $x$ depends on the arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$.

To prove that $X$ is complete, your goal is to show that an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converges to some $x\in X$.

The author's suggested plan of attack:

- First you should try to figure out the right choice of $x$, based on some fixed, arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$.$\\[4pt]$

  Next verify that $x\in X$ (as opposed to $x$ in some metric space $Y$ containing $X$, but with $x\not\in X$).$\\[4pt]$

  Finally, assuming you have the right $x$, show that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

As regards your misconception . . .

You can't claim at the outset that $x$ is a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$, since $x$ is not given. It's *your* job to find $x$ (for an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$), and to show that it works.

Comment: In your bullet points -- 1. I construct $x$ as limit of a cauchy sequence of $x_n$ 2. Then show $x \in X$. Why doesn't 1. imply 3.? If I construct $x$ as a limit of a cauchy sequence - doesn't this imply $x_n \rightarrow x$ (because I can take $1/n$ balls around my limit point)?

Comment: @yoshi: Because, assuming $X$ is a subset of some larger space $Y$, the sequence $(x_n)$ might converge to a point $x\in Y$, but with $x\not\in X$.

Comment: @yoshi: Also note: Just because you know that the sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, that doesn't automatically mean that it _has_ a limit. Of course, if the containing space $X$ is complete, then yes, the sequence $(x_n)$ will have a limit, but you don't know that $X$ is complete -- that's what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @yoshi: Perhaps your misunderstanding is this:$\;$In step $1$, you are finding a _candidate_ point $x$ which you _believe_ to be the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$. You need to make sure that $x\in X$, and of course, you need to prove that $x$ is actually the limit of $(x_n)$.

Comment: okay, but in constructing a candidate limit -- I have to use information about the cuachy sequence. doesn't this mean that the cauchy sequence *will* have a limit? (I haven't checked the space in which the limit lives in yet)

Comment: No, you can produce a candidate $x$ in terms of $(x_n)$, but just producing a candidate doesn't mean it qualifies. That's what steps $2$ and $3$ are for.

Comment: Okay almost there: could you provide an example of this?

Comment: The author does just that in the pages following his proposed template (e.g., example $1.5$-$1$).

Comment: He doesn't exactly follow this template -- that's I'm getting confused. For instance, when he's proving completness in Rn, he refers to a theorem that says R is complete, which itself relies on a general statement that cauchy convergence iff convergence in metric space. He doesn't produce any candidate only in terms of $(x_n)$'s

Comment: Of course you can use known (previously proved) completeness of related spaces to help  prove completeness of a target space.